# Better way to find if value matches list of regular expressions

Tags: regex, kotlin

Sample code, see if a value matches any regex from a list:

```
    private val regex: List<Regex> = ...

    fun matches(value: String): Boolean {
        regex.forEach { re ->
            if (re.matches(value))
                return true
        }
        return false
    }
```

It works, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this. Note that I **don't** want to evaluate all of them, but stop whenever there is a match.

Answer (score 4):

`fun matches(value: String) = regex.any { it.matches(value) }`

[any](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/any.html)

There are also similar functions:
[all](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/all.html),
[none](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/none.html)

Comment: Beautiful. The more I use Kotlin, the more I fall in love with it. Such good taste :-)

Comment: @AlA accept the answer please if it helped you

Comment: Any time you find yourself using a `for` loop, you should check whether the stdlib has an alternative — especially the [extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/) on `Iterable`, `Collection`, and `List` (which you can see in your IDE by simply type a dot after a list value). (Sometimes a loop is still the best approach, but it's always worth knowing the options.)